# Vertical alignment of nodes text

Tags: vertical-alignment, nodes

I have two nodes with different mathematical formulas above them. I would like to have them aligned as if they were written in the same line.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[fill=black] (0,0) circle (2pt);
   \draw[fill=black] (1,0) circle (2pt);
   \node[above] at (0,0) {$M_1$};
   \node[above] at (1,0) {$M$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer: You can set the alignment anchor of the nodes to the baseline of the text inside using `anchor=base`. You need to shift them a bit upwards then, however.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm, tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[fill=black] (0,0) circle (2pt);
   \draw[fill=black] (1,0) circle (2pt);
   \node[above=5pt, anchor=base] at (0,0) {$M_1$};
   \node[above=5pt, anchor=base] at (1,0) {$M$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One way is to write text above circles as labels and for them define `text depth`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
dot/.style = {circle, fill, minimum size=4mm,
              inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},
every label/.append style = {text  depth=0.5ex}
                        ]
\node[dot, label=above:$M_1$] at (0,0)  {};
\node[dot, label=above:$M$]   at (1,0)  {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly, this is the other solution, I was just about to add to my suggestion.

Comment: @JasperHabicht, you almost succeed :-),  with age my fingers are getting slower :-(